# How to stop dfwu1013.info from popping on my screen when ever I try to Google anything?

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome

I have a problem that is bothering me and I kindly request for help.

When ever I try to search / Google/browse something on the Internet using Google Chrome a website named Dfwu1013.info pops up on my  screen and I can't proceed to browse want I intended to browse.

Could someone be knowing what it is and how I can stop it?

Comment: It sounds like you've got some malware.  Create another user account, log into that and see if the problem goes away. Also, does it appear in Safari?  What version of macOS are you running?

Comment: Also try running something like MalwareBytes.

Answer (score 1):

Highly likely to be malware. Try reinstalling Chrome. If the problem persists, run an antivirus scan. Also try looking in the extensions or apps page in Chrome and remove unrecognized software.